# How to reduce memory usage while checking image size in php

Tags: php, performance, file-upload

Suppose I do not want to allow an image > 2MB to be uploaded and I check the image size as following

```
If($_FILES["image"]["size"] > 2100000) {
// .........
}
```

and

```
getimagesize($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]
```

Suppose User try to upload a very large size image of about 300 MB, This will cause a great memory usage and distrubance.

How can I control this?

Comment: Why not just use `MAX_FILE_SIZE` input?

Comment: The size really shouldn't impact this noticeably, it should be checking headers, for example, and not literally counting byte-by-byte.

Comment: Using MAX_FILE_SIZE will not solve the problem, because it can be easily bypassed by simple edit on the fly of the HTML source.

Comment: You can set the maximum upload size in php.ini (http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-max-filesize)

Answer (score 0):

```
ini_set('post_max_size', '2M');
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '2M');
```

This is to change the upload size allowed on runtime.

Or you can change the config in the php.ini (remeber to restart the web service), this will set a server-level limit on all your scripts, and cannot be bypassed easily like someone said in your comment